# Twitter home/timeline limit 200?

Tags: api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I know that Twitter API limit is 200 most recent tweets. But how pull more tweets? for example 1000 latest tweets of my Home Timeline.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [paging](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline#api-param-page).